# Jitsi configuration Lobby

Tags: jitsi

I have installed my own jitsi instance on a Ubuntu 18.04 server with NGINX and i want to have a lobby room and a login for modertors.
My Problem is that every "waiting for modertor" guest will directly go to the metting when the
moderator logged in. But i want that the guest then goes to the lobby and the moderator can put him to the conderence.

**My installed packeges are**

```
root@jitsi:~# dpkg -l | grep jitsi
ii  jitsi-meet                     2.0.5390-3                               all          WebRTC JavaScript video conferences
ii  jitsi-meet-prosody             1.0.4628-1                               all          Prosody configuration for Jitsi Meet
ii  jitsi-meet-turnserver          1.0.4628-1                               all          Configures coturn to be used with Jitsi Meet
ii  jitsi-meet-web                 1.0.4628-1                               all          WebRTC JavaScript video conferences
ii  jitsi-meet-web-config          1.0.4628-1                               all          Configuration for web serving of Jitsi Meet
ii  jitsi-videobridge2             2.1-416-g2f43d1b4-1                      all          WebRTC compatible Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU)
root@jitsi:~#
```

**the cofigurtion (Domainname are changed)**
/etc/prosody/conf.d/jitsi.mydomain.de.cfg.lua

```
plugin_paths = { "/usr/share/jitsi-meet/prosody-plugins/" }

-- domain mapper options, must at least have domain base set to use the mapper
muc_mapper_domain_base = "jitsi.mydomain.de";

turncredentials_secret = "WZPb5dhW3mWzqLTN";

turncredentials = {
    { type = "stun", host = "jitsi.mydomain.de", port = "3478" },
    { type = "turn", host = "jitsi.mydomain.de", port = "3478", transport = "udp" },
    { type = "turns", host = "jitsi.mydomain.de", port = "5349", transport = "tcp" }
};

cross_domain_bosh = false;
consider_bosh_secure = true;
-- https_ports = { }; -- Remove this line to prevent listening on port 5284

-- https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&version=2.1&config=intermediate&openssl=1.1.0g&guideline=5.4
ssl = {
    protocol = "tlsv1_2+";
    ciphers = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
}

VirtualHost "jitsi.mydomain.de"
    -- enabled = false -- Remove this line to enable this host
    -- authentication = "anonymous"
    authentication = "internal_hashed"
    -- Properties below are modified by jitsi-meet-tokens package config
    -- and authentication above is switched to "token"
    --app_id="example_app_id"
    --app_secret="example_app_secret"
    -- Assign this host a certificate for TLS, otherwise it would use the one
    -- set in the global section (if any).
    -- Note that old-style SSL on port 5223 only supports one certificate, and will always
    -- use the global one.
    ssl = {
        key = "/etc/prosody/certs/jitsi.mydomain.de.key";
        certificate = "/etc/prosody/certs/jitsi.mydomain.de.crt";
    }
    speakerstats_component = "speakerstats.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    conference_duration_component = "conferenceduration.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    -- we need bosh
    modules_enabled = {
        "bosh";
        "pubsub";
        "ping"; -- Enable mod_ping
        "speakerstats";
        "turncredentials";
        "conference_duration";
        "muc_lobby_rooms";
    }
    c2s_require_encryption = false
    lobby_muc = "lobby.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    main_muc = "conference.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    -- muc_lobby_whitelist = { "recorder.jitsi.mydomain.de" } -- Here we can whitelist jibri to enter lobby enabled rooms

VirtualHost "guest.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    authentication = "anonymous"
    c2s_require_encryption = false
    modules_enabled = {
        "muc_lobby_rooms";
    }
    lobby_muc = "lobby.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    main_muc = "conference.jitsi.mydomain.de"

Component "lobby.jitsi.mydomain.de" "muc"
    storage = "memory"
    restrict_room_creation = true
    muc_room_locking = false
    muc_room_default_public_jids = true

Component "conference.jitsi.mydomain.de" "muc"
    storage = "none"
    modules_enabled = {
        "muc_meeting_id";
        "muc_domain_mapper";
        --"token_verification";
    }
    admins = { "focus@auth.jitsi.mydomain.de" }
    muc_room_locking = false
    muc_room_default_public_jids = true

-- internal muc component
Component "internal.auth.jitsi.mydomain.de" "muc"
    storage = "none"
    modules_enabled = {
        "ping";
    }
    admins = { "focus@auth.jitsi.mydomain.de", "jvb@auth.jitsi.mydomain.de" }
    muc_room_locking = false
    muc_room_default_public_jids = true

VirtualHost "auth.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    ssl = {
        key = "/etc/prosody/certs/auth.jitsi.mydomain.de.key";
        certificate = "/etc/prosody/certs/auth.jitsi.mydomain.de.crt";
    }
    authentication = "internal_plain"

Component "focus.jitsi.mydomain.de"
    component_secret = "87onbCZv"

Component "speakerstats.jitsi.mydomain.de" "speakerstats_component"
    muc_component = "conference.jitsi.mydomain.de"

Component "conferenceduration.jitsi.mydomain.de" "conference_duration_component"
    muc_component = "conference.jitsi.mydomain.de"

Component "lobby.jitsi.mydomain.de" "muc"
    storage = "none"
    restrict_room_creation = true
    muc_room_locking = false
    muc_room_default_public_jids = true
```